# Adding normal distribution to geom_bar plot in R with percentages

Tags: r, overlay, percentage, normal-distribution, geom-bar

I am trying to add a normal distribution to my bar plot, but I have converted my plot to be in percentages. With adding a normal distribution it switches to density and it doesn't seem to work.

This is my plot:

```
percentage_plot <- ggplot(data = verpleegkundige) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Afspraken_op_teamniveau, y = ..prop.., group = 1), stat = "count") +
  labs(x = "Afspraken op teamniveau", y = "Percentage", fill = "Afspraken_op_teamniveau") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format())
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data using `dput()`? It makes it much easier for others to help if they can run your code.